# Is there a way to reboot a Pixel 4a with a broken power button?

Tags: reboot

Power button broke months ago. I've been very careful to never let it shut off, but last night it finally happened.

Is there any way to make it reboot? I tried pressing Volume- and plugging in, and that brought up the boot menu, but you need to use the power button to select anything from the boot menu so now I'm stuck. In fact, I may be worse off because now I'm stuck in the boot menu.

I tried `adb restart`, but adb doesn't see the device. (It can see other Android devices, so I know adb is installed and functioning.)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Addictive Tips](https://www.addictivetips.com/android/turn-on-an-android-phone-with-a-broken-power-button/), you can do this on a Pixel phone in the method you started on:

> Press volume up and/or down (varies by manufacturer) and plug your device into your computer. Use the following as an outline.
>
> Nexus and Pixel Devices: Press and hold the volume down and plug in the device. When the Google splash screen appears, release it.
>
> If your device does not go into Bootloader using the above method, drop a comment with your device name and model and we’ll try to figure out how to work that one out.
>
> Once the phone is in bootloader mode, run the following command in ADB (must be connected to a PC);
>
> `fastboot continue`
>
> It will immediately boot your phone.

Please note the error from the provided site noticed by @Robert in the comments below: ADB commands are different than fastboot commands. When the device is in fastboot mode, you use `fastboot` rather than `ADB` when targeting the device. You can obtain the drivers necessary from [Google](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb) or somewhere like [XDA](https://xdaforums.com/t/official-tool-windows-adb-fastboot-and-drivers-15-seconds-adb-installer-v1-4-3.2588979/).

Comment: The last part about `run the following command in ADB` is nonsense. A phone can only be in adb mode or fastboot mode. Therefore you can never run a fastboot command "in adb". What you mean is execute `fastboot continue` from within the command-line respectively terminal of the PC.

Comment: I did try all that. Unfortunately, once in the boot menu, adb cannot see the phone. I finally gave up and took it to a repair shop to have the power button replaced.

Comment: @EdwardFalk That what I was talking about. When you are in boot menu the phone is in fastboot mode, so it will never ever be accessible via adb. You need to install fastboot drivers and use fastboot binary on the PC.

Comment: Edited to include the distinction and clarification, thanks, @Robert!